# ASP.NET Identity UserManager IIdentityMessageService pass extra parameters to SendAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I've successfully created custom email service provider for UserManager by extending `IIdentityMessageService`:

```
public class ExchangeEmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Host = "mail.example.com";
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"noreply", "P@ssw0rd");

            var from = new MailAddress("no-reply@example.com");
            var to = new MailAddress(message.Destination);

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to)
            {
                Subject = message.Subject,
                Body = message.Body,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `UserManager`'s Create I'm creating new instance of my service and assigning it to `EmailService`:

```
userManager.EmailService = new ExchangeEmailService();
```

This all works fine, but I have requirement to send emails from different email addresses, based on place this is called from, unfortunately `UserManager.SendEmailAsync` isn't allowing me to pass anything except userId, subject and body.

Ideally I'd like to be able to specify email address when calling `SendEmailAcync` or enum value.

I've searched in [UserManager source](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs) and I thought about creating custom `SendEmailAsync` implementation, but I'd have to change multiple places - IIdentityMessageService, UserManager.

I know I can create new interface and build my email sending class on it, but I'd like to keep changes to minimum.

What I'd like to get:
I'd like to have enum containing names of mailboxes:

```
public enum Mailboxes
{
    Noreply = 0,
    Service = 1,
    Contact = 2
}
```

and be able to call `SendEmailAsync` with that additional parameter:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Account created", "Nice email content.", Mailboxes.Noreply );
```

I'm aware that I can set different title and use same email address, but this is requirement I got.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't see a way around this without overloading `SendEmailAsync` in your `ApplicationUserManager` class that extends the `UserManager` in Identity. You could then extend the `IdentityMessage` class so it has a `FromAddress` property. Your new overloaded `SendEmailAsync` would then have a `fromAddress` parameter that you can use to create an instance of your custom `IdentityMessage`. However, you would also have to lookup the current user in your new `SendEmailAsync` in order to retrieve the destination address.

Comment: @philreed I thought about extending `IdentityMessage`, passing instance of my class to `SendEmailAsync` and then inside `SendAsync` checking if `IdentityMessage` is MyEmailMessage, then up-cast it and use that new property. I'll wait a bit longer because I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yea I don't see why that wouldn't work, it is simpler than I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Misiu, A hack would be to create a model to store what you want sent to the service and then serialize it (JSON maybe) as the body of the method call. The service would then deserialize the model, construct the email with the custom info and then send the email.

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to create a model to store what you want sent to the service

```
public class MessageBody {
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public MailBoxes Source { get; set; }
}
```

and then serialize it (JSON maybe) as the `body` parameter of the `SendEmailAsync` method call.

```
var message = new MessageBody {
    Body = "Nice email content.",
    Source = Mailboxes.Noreply
};

var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Account created", body);
```

The service would then deserialize the model, construct the email with the custom info and then send the email.

```
public class ExchangeEmailService : IIdentityMessageService {
    readonly IMailBoxProvider provider;

    public ExchangeEmailService(IMailBoxProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message) {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
            client.Host = "mail.example.com";
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"noreply", "P@ssw0rd");

            //Get the body and from address
            var fromEmailAddress = "default-email@example.com";
            var body = message.Body;
            try {
                var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageBody>(body);
                if(msg != null) {
                    body = msg.Body;
                    fromEmailAddress = provider.GetMailbox(msg.Source);
                }
            } catch { }

            var from = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress);
            var to = new MailAddress(message.Destination);

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to)
            {
                Subject = message.Subject,
                Body = body,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And just make sure to assigning it to `UserManager.EmailService`:

```
userManager.EmailService = new ExchangeEmailService(new MailBoxProvider());
```